# How can one use a selector class that is written in a separate CSS file?

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors, external

So I tried displaying an image by making a selector class with a `background-image` attribute then calling it using the `<div>` tag. The first time the selector class was between the `<head>` tags. Everything seems to work fine:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body, html {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .bg {
                /* The image used */
                background-image: url("images.jpeg");

                /* Full height */
                height: 100%;

                /* Center and scale the image nicely */
                background-position: center;
                background-size: cover;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But when I put the selector class inside a separate CSS file, it doesn’t seem to work. Here is the code for the HTML file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body, html {
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here’s for the CSS:

```
.bg {
   /* The image used */
   background-image: url("images.jpeg");

   /* Full height */
   height: 100%;

   /* Center and scale the image nicely */
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Could someone please kindly tell me what I did wrong? I thank you in advance!

Comment: So where did you include the separate css file in your html?

Comment: May be, you are storing the CSS file inside a subfolder. If that's the case, then, in respect to the CSS file's location, the image file's path has to be specified. If the CSS file is inside 1 subfolder then `background-image: url("../images.jpeg");` will do the job. I think you are stuck here, bro. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to import your separate css file on your html page :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

And be careful for the right path.

Comment: Avoid answering questions that will be closed as a problem that couldn't be reproduced

Comment: Ok @AnuragSrivastava, thanks for the advice, it is better ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `link` tag inside of `head` in your HTML to connect your styles to the HTML.

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="xxx.css">
</head>
```

Replace `xxx.css` with the path to your css file.

Check the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) for details.